# Maximum Possible Data Transfer Speed Over Local Wi-Fi Network

Tags: connection, wifi, local-network

I have encountered an issue with limited data transfer speed over Wi-Fi between two devices. I have a TP-Link EC220 G5 router operating on both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz frequencies with speeds up to 300 Mbps and 867 Mbps, respectively. Both devices (PC and laptop) are connected to the router's network and support 802.11ac/n.

Characteristics of network interfaces for devices:

TP-Link EC220 G5 Router:

```
    2.4 GHz: Up to 300 Mbps
    5 GHz: Up to 867 Mbps (802.11ac/n)
```

PC:

```
wlp11s0   IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MoorMoor_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 78:8C:B5:DC:9B:08   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0


Wireless interface
          product: MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
          vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
          logical name: wlp11s0
```

Laptop:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MoorMoor_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 78:8C:B5:DC:9B:08   
          Bit Rate=585 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0

Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: d8:12:65:e4:44:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
```

To achieve the maximum transfer speed, I developed a multi-threaded server and client in Python designed for file transfer. However, regardless of my efforts, the data transfer speed does not exceed 200 Mbps. I tried using multiple concurrent TCP connections, but it did not increase the speed.

**Question:** Why is the transfer speed limited, and how can I achieve the maximum possible speed over Wi-Fi between these devices?

UPD: Moving the laptop to another room increased the transfer speed to 250 Mbps.